# Print all days date between multiple two dates in SQL Server with set-based approach

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am able to get all days between two dates with this.

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20140101' ,
        @MaxDate DATE = '20140106';

SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
    DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
FROM    
    sys.all_objects a
CROSS JOIN 
    sys.all_objects b
```

Now I got a result set like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| ID  |      StartDate          |         EndDate         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  1  | 2017-05-12 00:00:00.000 | 2017-05-15 00:00:00.000 |
|  2  | 2018-08-10 00:00:00.000 | 2018-08-13 00:00:00.000 |
|  3  | 2019-02-12 00:00:00.000 | 2019-02-13 00:00:00.000 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to find all the days between all start date and end date in this table, and the expected outcome should be like the following:

```
---------------------------
|        AllDates         |
---------------------------
| 2017-05-12 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-05-13 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-05-14 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-05-15 00:00:00.000 |
| 2018-08-10 00:00:00.000 | 
| 2018-08-11 00:00:00.000 | 
| 2018-08-12 00:00:00.000 | 
| 2018-08-13 00:00:00.000 |
| 2019-02-12 00:00:00.000 | 
| 2019-02-13 00:00:00.000 |
---------------------------
```

Without using user defined function in SQL Server, can this be achieve only by using set-based approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
;WITH Tally AS (
   SELECT TOP 365 ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY a.object_id ) - 1 AS rn
   FROM sys.all_objects a
   CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
)
SELECT StartDate, EndDate,
       DATEADD(DAY, t.rn, StartDate) AS AllDates
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate) + 1) AS c(days)
JOIN Tally AS t ON t.rn + 1 <= c.days
ORDER BY StartDate, AllDates
```

This applies the same logic of the original query to your table.

**Note**: You have to use a limit to the number of rows returned by cross joining the `sys.all_objects`, otherwise the query becomes inefficient. If the difference between `StartDate` and `EndDate` is always less than a year, then you can use `365` as the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the tally table for this like in the below code

You can use the below code for filling tally table

```
SELECT TOP 1000000 N=IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1)
INTO dbo.Tally1K
FROM master.dbo.syscolumns a CROSS JOIN master.dbo.syscolumns  b;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Tally1K ADD CONSTRAINT NBR_pk PRIMARY KEY(N);
```

Now use this tally table for filling us dates.

```
select DATEADD(DAY, t.N - 1, CONVERT(datetime, '02/25/2014'))
from Tally1K t
where t.N < DATEDIFF(DAY, '02/24/2014', '04/26/2014') + 1
order by 1;
```

For more information about tally tables please go to the link below

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/